# React Material UI Tooltips Disable Animation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React Material UI's Tooltip Component in my React application.

```
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
...
...
<Tooltip title="Add" arrow>
    <Button>Arrow</Button>
</Tooltip>
...
...
```

I want to disable the entry and exit animations. How can I achieve this in the latest version

Comment: Can you add more code related to Tooltip component?

Comment: I know I probably need to use ```withStyles``` and override some predefined style in some predefined Component, but I don't what is that style and which Component would that be.

Comment: You can check in React dev tools for the props that are present for the `Tooltip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just disable/mock the transition component.
ie: render automatically the children like this:

`const FakeTransitionComponent = ({ children }) => children;`

```
<Tooltip
  title="tooltip title"
  TransitionComponent={FakeTransitionComponent}
  // or TransitionComponent={({ children}) => children}
>
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
</Tooltip>
```

Here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-field-ivoeq?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `TransitionComponent` and the `TransitionProps` to solve this.

Use the `Fade` Transition component with `timeout: 0` as the properties for the transition component:

```
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import Fade from "@material-ui/core/Fade";
...
<Tooltip
    title="Add"
    arrow
    TransitionComponent={Fade}
    TransitionProps={{ timeout: 0 }}
>
    <Button>Arrow</Button>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used Incepter's solution, that is clean. If anyone is looking for a TypeScript solution here it is.

```js
const FakeTransitionComponent = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  TransitionProps & { children?: React.ReactElement<any, any> }
>(
  (
    {
      appear,
      onEnter,
      onEntered,
      onEntering,
      onExit,
      onExited,
      onExiting,
      ...props
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    props.in = undefined;
    return <div {...props} ref={ref}></div>;
  }
);
```

TransitionProps are not passed to the wrapper element, because they would all  cause React warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass React.Fragment as TransitionComponent

```
<Tooltip
  title="tooltip title"
  TransitionComponent={React.Fragment}

>
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to create a simple `NoTransition` component:

```
export const NoTransition = React.forwardRef<
  React.ReactFragment,
  TransitionProps
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
>(({ children }, ref) => {
    return <>{ children }</>;
});
```

And do `TransitionComponent={ NoTransition }`.

Also, do not omit the `ref` param or you will get a warning too:

> Warning: forwardRef render functions accept exactly two parameters: props and ref. Did you forget to use the ref parameter?

Just adding `TransitionProps={{ timeout: 0 }}`, without setting `TransitionComponent`, will also work, but there's no need to render the default `TransitionComponent` in that case.

**Some of the options proposed in other answers will throw errors or warnings:**

Doing `TransitionComponent={ Fragment }` will result in the following warning:

> Warning: Invalid prop `appear` supplied to `React.Fragment`. React.Fragment can only have `key` and `children` props.

Doing `TransitionComponent={ ({ children }) => children }` will result in this other warnings (might change a bit depending if you are using a `Tooltip`, `Modal` or other component):

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(Modal)`. Expected an element that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally use a plain function component for an element instead? For more information see https://mui.com/r/caveat-with-refs-guide

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `ForwardRef(ModalUnstyled)`. Expected an element that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally use a plain function component for an element instead? For more information see https://mui.com/r/caveat-with-refs-guide

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? Check the render method of `Unstable_TrapFocus`.

And potentially also this error:

> Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I'm using `"@mui/material": "^5.5.2"`.