# React How to remove the animation of Material-UI Select

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the React Material UI's Select Component. I wish to remove or speeden the animation that comes when the menu is opening. I tried something like:

```
 <Select
     ...
     TransitionComponent={({children}) => children}
 >
     <MenuItem value={...}>...</MenuItem>
     ...
 </Select>
```

But this is not working, please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add this to your stylesheet:

```css
.MuiMenu-paper {
    transition-duration: 0s !important;
}
```

This basically overrides the transition duration of the select dropdown and sets it to 0 seconds.

You can also change the duration according to what you like (make it faster). The default animation duration is:

```css
transition-duration: 251ms, 167ms;
```

Comment: is there also an entry delay? because even now it takes a second before appearing.. i want to make it completely smooth...

Comment: It doesn't seem like there is any entry delay you can control, as far as I can see. I think the delay you are referring to is just the time it takes React to render your component.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it doesn't work:

MUI `<Select />` API don't have props **TransitionComponent**, as well as some other components like `<Tooltip />` do have

Refer: API document of

- MUI [Tooltip](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/)
- MUI [Select](https://material-ui.com/api/select/)

Related QA: [React Material UI Tooltips Disable Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139778/react-material-ui-tooltips-disable-animation)

---

#### Solution

Override the **transition** style would be fine.

```
div.MuiPaper-root {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

---

[image]

---

#### Explanation

The HTML structure for options:

Since it's been dynamically generated outside the main component, it's not suitable for us to directly set styles for them.

However, we can optionally override the styles by those classNames like **MuiPaper-root**, or some other ways like a given id.

```
<div
  class="MuiPaper-root MuiMenu-paper MuiPopover-paper MuiPaper-elevation8 MuiPaper-rounded"
  tabindex="-1"
  style="opacity: 1; transform: none; min-width: 40px; transition: opacity 251ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, transform 167ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms; top: 16px; left: 16px; transform-origin: -8px 7.7px;"
>
  <ul
    class="MuiList-root MuiMenu-list MuiList-padding"
    role="listbox"
    tabindex="-1"
  >
    ...
  </ul>
</div>;
```

[image]

Comment: good answer, as also asked to the other answerer, is there also an entry delay? because even now it takes a second before appearing.. i want to make it completely smooth... –

Comment: @DivyanshGoenka Post another question with online demo would work for your demand

Answer (score 2):

To add to keikai's answer, you can also do this globally with a theme change:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiPaper: {
      root: {
        transition: 'none !important'
      },
    },
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For those that are using a corresponding Material UI `InputLabel` component with a mui `Select` component, I was able to pass in the following props to the `InputLabel` component to disable the animation and shrink altogether:

```
<div>
   <FormControl>
     <InputLabel
       disableAnimation={true}
       shrink={false}
       ...
     >
       {`some label`}
     </InputLabel>
     <Select>
      {`...`}
     </Select>
   </FormControl>
 </div>
```

[MUI Input Label API](https://material-ui.com/api/input-label/#props)