# How to customise React Material UI's Tab Component's text style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React Material UI library's Tab Component. I want to remove any `textTransform` the library may be applying to capitalise the tab labels. I have tried this:

```
const CustomTab = withStyles({
    ".MuiButtonBase-root": {textTransform: "none"}
})(Tab);
```

But it doesn't seem to work, please help

Comment: Any online demo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226270/react-how-to-remove-the-animation-of-material-ui-select/61226717#61226717

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you must use the [`root` rule](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#css) which is equivalent to `.MuiTab-root` CSS class name:

```
const CustomTab = withStyles({
  root: {
    textTransform: "none"
  }
})(Tab);
```

example from Material-UI doc: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#customized-tabs

Answer (score 2):

you can use sx prop to transform the text or add any custom css

```
<Tab  sx={{textTransform :"none"}} label = "add product"/>
```

reference [Material-UI](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)